# XMLHttpRequest (XHR) GET requests in GO

Tags: ajax, go

I have uploaded an image on a server powered by Golang. I want to show the same image in a HTML / JS page using XMLHttpRequest (XHR).

I'm having following challenges -
The static file server

```
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
```

is local to Go system and its template system. The Javascript doesn't know this system and can't find the required file.

So, while the img in HTML works (img src="/public/300x300.gif") works, this -

```
   xhr.open("GET", "/public/300x300.gif", true);   
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    xhr.send();
```

is not working.

How can I load an image on the page using AJAX while the file is available in Golang's virtual file system?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not working". There are a like a hundred things that could go wrong.

Comment: 1.
/public/300x300.gif is registered in the virtual file system via http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
2.
It is not understood by the client side Javascript. So,   xhr.open("GET", "/public/300x300.gif", true); doesn't get the path right and the Ajax call fails
3. 
It works well in a PHP backend where the file system is not virtual, unlike Go Server.

Comment: Was the error code / error message you get when execution the request?

Comment: On xhr.send();, there is no error. But the image is not loaded.

Comment: There has to be a HTTP status code.

Comment: let me revert you on this